# canvas in python not creating multiple objects in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter-canvas

I want to make multiple circles on a canvas so I used a while loop to create n 'planets'

```py
while planets_on_screen <= number_of_planets:
    tag = "planet_no" + str(planets_on_screen)
    planet = frame_canvas.create_oval(540 + planets_on_screen * effecter, 240, 560 + planets_on_screen *                   effecter, 260,fill="white", tags=tag)
    planet_list.append(planet)
    planets_on_screen += 1
    frame_canvas.update()
```

What I wanted it to do is create n planets each separated by a small distance, but it just moves the circle across the screen, Deleting the pervious one and drawing the next.

What am I doing wrong

I tried used functions but got the same result

Comment: try creating all the planets and then at the very end, outside of the while loop, call `frame_canvase.update()`